# How to install and use python libraries in mac using PIP with terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask, pip

Firstly i'm new to python environment.

I installed PIP in mac using terminal and the python version is 2.7.16. I want to install and use Simple Image annatator(https://github.com/sgp715/simple_image_annotator).

I install flask(pip install flask) and i did cd into the cloned folder if simple image annotator. For reference please see the github repo for installation steps.

Than after i don't know what to do to use this library if i run this command(python app.py /images/directory) it gives No files.

How can i install and use the simple image annotator in mac can somebody please tell me the setup process steps.

working with python libraries is entirely new to me. Thanks in advance.

BELOW IS EDITED QUESTION FOR MORE EXPLANATION:

I installed flask and moved to the cloned folder please see the terminal commands as shown in screenshot.

[image]

Next remaining installation steps are:

1. start the app
2. `$ python app.py /images/directory`

you can also specify the file you would like the annotations output to (out.csv is the default)

3. `$ python app.py /images/directory --out test.csv`
4. open http://127.0.0.1:5000/tagger in your browser
   only tested on Chrome

I don't know how to execute remaining steps. images are available in downloads/images folder in my mac.

How to execute these commands?

---

Screenshots to explain more:

[image]

[image]

Comment: From what I could see in the [source code](https://github.com/sgp715/simple_image_annotator/blob/b10b3eb0fbdf4d4765b306feb4115ddca0409d26/app.py#L82) you should not type `/images/directory` literally in you command but use the path to your existing images on your own disk. Now, this is not really a question about programming but on how to use a piece of software you have found. You should direct your questions to the [issue page](https://github.com/sgp715/simple_image_annotator/issues) in the github account you are referencing.

Comment: I Have updated my question please look into it. I run command python app.py downloads/images command it generated out.csv file in the folder. what is next process to annotate images using this library.

Comment: Step 1. Start the app.... which app i need to start python app or terminal? etc and how to open this on chrome Step 4. http://127.0.0.1:5000/tagger

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be from your python version.

Try with python3 (if installed)

`python3 app.py /images/directory`

Comment: I tried with python 3.5.4 but same result. I edited my question please look over it. I think it's not due to the python 2.7.16  it still supports  that, it's due to lack of my knowledge on installation process of python libraries in mac.

Comment: I ran python app.py downloads/images command it created out.csv file. I need to get all images annotations in the file how can i get annoations using this library.

Comment: Step 1. Start the app.... which app i need to start python app or terminal? etc and how to open this in chrome Step 4:  http://127.0.0.1:5000/tagger

Comment: If you run the command in your terminal, it will start a local server that works with flask, (if you close the terminal, it will stop the server)

Comment: Then open your browser and put this URL :  [127.0.0.1:5000/tagger](http://127.0.0.1:5000/tagger)

Comment: After running this command(python app.py downloads/images) i opened http://127.0.0.1:5000/tagger in chrome but it shows this site can't be reached. For reference i added scrrenshots at the end of my question please look over it.

Comment: What is the result of `pip install flask`  Screen ?

Comment: pip is already installed (https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6led.png) i added first screenshot in my question.

Comment: Try the upgrade of pip

Comment: Yeah i upgraded to pip-19.1(pip install --upgrade pip) but same result.

Comment: If I doesn't work,  use `pip3` pip for python 3 then `pip3 install flask`

Comment: pip3 install flask This command gives error:-  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: ) and i installed Python 3.5.4 in my mac @lupaulus

Comment: I don't know anything more about this because I haven't a mac but on Linux It works fine. It should be working